# Python Twisted client implementation with reconnection every 2 seconds

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted

I use `ReconnectingClientFactory` for implementing client with reconnection feature.

```
# ...

class ClientProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory
# ...

class ClientFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        self.resetDelay()
        return ClientProtocol(self)

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        ReconnectingClientFactory.clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason)
# ...
```

It works, but reconnect delay exponentially grows after fail. What's the best way to have two seconds delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`maxDelay`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.html#maxDelay) to 2:

```
class YourClientFactory(ReconnectingClientFactory):
    maxDelay = 2.0
    # ...
```